# Laravel - errno: 150 Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed - One to Many relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys

I have two Models: Concorso and State. The relationships are the following: a Concorso belongs to a State; a State has many Concorso.
Just so you know, Concorsi is the plural of Concorso.

**create_concorsi_table**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('concorsi', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('state_id')->constrained();
            $table->string('nome');
            $table->text('descrizione');
            $table->date('data_accettazione');
            $table->date('data_scadenza');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**create_states_table**

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('states', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('status');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

When I run "php artisan migrate", I received this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `inertia_example_1`.`concorsi` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `concorsi` add constraint `concorsi_state_id_foreign` foreign key (`state_id`) references `states` (`id`))
```

I really can't understand the poblem. The syntax seems correct, what could be the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Order is important. Create your `states` table first if you want to reference it

Comment: Alright now it works! But, in order fot the "states" migration to be generated before the other one, I renamed the migration file with an erlier date.. Is there another way apart from renaming the migration file or is this the right way to go?

Comment: That's the right way to go, glad it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concorsi need the states for his creation. Migration creation process is sequencial. Check [migrations in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations)

Comment: Alright now it works! But, in order fot the "states" migration to be generated before the other one, I renamed the migration file with an erlier date.. Is there another way apart from renaming the migration file or is this the right way to go?

Comment: Migrations is useful exactly to avoid having to modify files and not to lose stored data. It is like keeping a repository of changes in the database. But for that, please open another question. @nicoblue